# How to use .Substring?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-7, xaml

I know that this looks like a noob question, but I don't know what's going on that I keep getting wrong values when using the .substring. I have used it in java like this

```
text = "stackoverflow"
text1 = text.substring(start, end);
```

where start can be any number `< text.length` and it works perfectly. Example

```
text1 = text.substring(9, text.length);
```

Should give me `"flow"` but if I try that exact code in Visual Basic it gives me the full text `"stackoverflow"`  so... what am I doing wrong?

Here's my code for it:

```
TextBox2.Text = bin.Substring(9, text.length)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter is not end position, but length of desired output string:

```
'Declaration
Public Function Substring ( _
    startIndex As Integer, _
    length As Integer _
) As String
```

This should return `"flow"`:

```
TextBox2.Text = bin.Substring(9,4)
```

Comment: Ugh.., so easy solution thank you very much. Will accept it soon, page don't let me do it.